Shared spdlog used by two separate .so files results in segfault
I have an executable that loads two so library files. The second so file that is loaded results in a segfault (the order of which one to load first does not have any impact on the segfault). I link against the shared spdlog
I have tried to reproduce the issue on a minimal example, however, I have not managed to recreate the problem. Although, I will still share the minimal example whether someone can help providing some guides or hints into why this might happen.
log_wrap.hpp
#ifndef LOG_WRAP_HPP
#define LOG_WRAP_HPP

#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <spdlog/sinks/stdout_color_sinks.h>
#include <cxxabi.h>

class LogImpl;

class LogRegister {
    inline static std::vector<spdlog::sink_ptr> sinks;
    inline static std::mutex mmutex;
    inline static std::atomic<bool> sss{ false };

    template <typename SINK, typename... ARGS>
    static void add_sink(std::atomic<bool>& state, ARGS... args) {
        const std::lock_guard lock(mmutex);
        if (state.load()) return;
        sinks.push_back(std::make_shared<SINK>(args...));
        auto& new_sink = sinks.back();
        spdlog::apply_all([&new_sink](const std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& l) { l->sinks().push_back(new_sink); });
        state.exchange(true);
    }
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<LogImpl> register_logger(const std::string& app_id);
    static void enable_stdout() { add_sink<spdlog::sinks::stdout_color_sink_mt>(sss); }
};

class LogImpl : public spdlog::logger
{
private:
    std::string m_name_wo_prefix;
    std::string m_prefix;
public:
    void set_prefix(std::string prefix)
    {
        m_prefix = std::move(prefix);
        name_ = m_prefix + m_name_wo_prefix;
    }

    explicit LogImpl(const std::string& name) : spdlog::logger(name), m_name_wo_prefix(name) {}

    template <typename ITERATOR>
    LogImpl(const std::string& name, ITERATOR begin, ITERATOR end)
        : spdlog::logger(name, begin, end), m_name_wo_prefix(name)
    {}
};

template<typename T>
class LogWrap : public std::shared_ptr<LogImpl> {
private:
    static std::string make_logger_name()
    {
        int status = 0;
        const char *tid = typeid(T).name();
        const char *result_cstr = abi::__cxa_demangle(tid, nullptr, nullptr, &status);
        if (status)
        {
            free((void *)result_cstr);
            return tid;
        }
        std::string result(result_cstr);
        free((void *) result_cstr);
        return result;
    }

public:
    LogWrap() : std::shared_ptr<LogImpl>(LogRegister::register_logger(make_logger_name())) {}
};


inline std::shared_ptr<LogImpl> LogRegister::register_logger(const std::string& app_id)
{
    if (!spdlog::get(app_id)){
        spdlog::register_logger(std::make_shared<LogImpl>(app_id, begin(sinks), end(sinks)));
    }
    auto result_spdlog = spdlog::get(app_id);
    auto result_impl = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<LogImpl>(result_spdlog);
    return result_impl;
}

#endif //LOG_WRAP_HPP

common_class.hpp
#ifndef COMMON_CLASS_HPP
#define COMMON_CLASS_HPP

#include "log_wrap.hpp"

class CommonClass {

    inline static LogWrap<CommonClass> logger;
public:
    CommonClass();
};
#endif //COMMON_CLASS_HPP

common_class.cpp
#include "common_class.hpp"


CommonClass::CommonClass()
{
    logger->info("hello world!");
}

Plugin 1
#include "common_class.hpp"

extern "C" {
    __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
    void plugin() {
        CommonClass c;
        return;
    };
}

Plugin 2
#include "common_class.hpp"

extern "C" {
    __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
    void plugin2() {
        CommonClass c;
    };
}

Executable:
#include "log_wrap.hpp"
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>

static const std::string plugin_func = "plugin";

int main() {

    void *m_lib{ nullptr };
    void *m_lib2{ nullptr };
    LogRegister::enable_stdout();

    m_lib = dlopen("./libdum_plugin.so", RTLD_LAZY );
    m_lib2 = dlopen("./libliba.so", RTLD_LAZY );
    assert(m_lib);
    assert(m_lib2);

}

CMakefile
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(ReproduceSegfault
        VERSION 0.1
        LANGUAGES CXX )
find_package(spdlog REQUIRED)
add_library(obj_ OBJECT common_class.cpp )
target_link_libraries(obj_ PUBLIC spdlog::spdlog)
set_property(TARGET obj_ PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--no-undefined")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--no-allow-shlib-undefined")
add_library(liba SHARED)
target_sources(liba PRIVATE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:obj_>)
target_link_libraries(liba PUBLIC spdlog::spdlog)
add_library(dum_plugin SHARED)
target_sources(dum_plugin PRIVATE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:obj_> plugin.cpp)
target_link_libraries(dum_plugin PUBLIC liba spdlog::spdlog)
add_library(dum_plugin2 SHARED)
target_sources(dum_plugin2 PRIVATE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:obj_> plugin2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(dum_plugin2 PUBLIC liba spdlog::spdlog)
add_executable(dum_exe  dum_exe.cpp )
target_link_libraries(dum_exe PUBLIC spdlog::spdlog)

As mentioned, the above example does not result in a segfault, however, it does resemble the same situation I have in my prod code. One key difference I observed with the above example, is that the static log registration of CommonClass only happens once!. So when I open the second plugin I do not observe any other static registration of CommonClass, however, in my real application I got many similar to CommonClass where I see that the static initialization of the logger is invoked multiple times when loading the two plugins... Whether this is the problem I am not sure.
I get the segfault at this line:
auto result_impl = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<LogImpl>(result_spdlog);

I did run through the debugger and result_spdlog is not a nullptr (and even if it was I guess result_impl would just be a nullptr itself). However, in this case the segfault occurs within dynamic_pointer_cast

I guess you're running into what is called the "static initialization fiasco". So do you know about abstract baseclasses and dependency injection, and why you should avoid global variables and singletons? Your logging should be initialized from main and you should pass references to logging to the classes (or functions) in other TU using an abstract baseclass to logging

I am not sure I can see how  the static initialization fiasco might happen, when the segfault occurs when we load the second plugin.
Yes I am aware of those :), although which static part do you see as the problem? Because I guess we cannot get around the fact the spdlog relies on singleton for the registry?

That is the point I am making, you can get around that singleton issue. By only creating an instance in main (wrapped in a wrapper class and then only pass an interface to the wrapper class around). I suspect a static initialization issue, I did not review in detail (but I always get suspicious when I see singletons being used over multiple translation units... you just lose control)

do we not loose the fact that we no longer can log the name of which class the log came from:
Now I got inline static LogWrap logger;  and I made so whenver this logger logs something, the pattern (prefix of the log) would include the class nanme
